# Why I can import the package in the parent directory in PyCharm, however, it reports an error in the terminal?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-module, python-packaging

Why I can import the package in the parent directory in PyCharm, however, it reports an error in the terminal?

I will use the following toy code to show my problem. For example, the project structure is like the following:
[image]

In `hello.py` is:

```
def func():
    print("hello")
```

In `test.py` is

```
import mypackage.hello
mypackage.hello.func()
```

Now if I run `test.py` in PyCharm, it runs perfectly and prints `hello`. However, if I use the terminal and `cd` to `test` directory, and run command `python test.py`, it reports the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mypackage.hello
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage'
```

PS: I use the same environment in both PyCharm and terminal.

Question:

1. Why does it show different results in PyCharm IDE and terminal?
2. In general, what's the correct style to import a package in the parent directory such that I can run both in the terminal and IDE?

Comment: You might want to look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830917/how-does-pycharm-handle-relative-imports-of-modules). The executive summary is that PyCharm does things for you, making it more error-proof, whereas running the file in terminal will not benefit from PyCharm's internal management of the system path.

Comment: I had this too, my solution is to cd to the `python` directory (project root) and run `python -m test.test`. This is only a comment because the answer should involve something answering question 2.

Comment: @Sadap Your method works!

Comment: @Sadap advice is good. Also my advice would be: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61698924/11138259

Comment: pycharm does a lot of things behind it, so when you switch to the terminal, things are no longer so easy. If you must run the module file, use `python -m`